# Why isn't my gridview showing the footer row? vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to add a footer row to my gridview, containing the totals of each column in said gridview, my aspx code is:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTablaMensual_fichas" runat="server" />
</div>
```

And my vb code is this:

```
gv.DataSource = dt
Dim conexiones As Decimal = 0
Dim bajas As Decimal = 0
Dim reconex As Decimal = 0
Dim cortes As Decimal = 0
Dim variacion As Decimal = 0
Dim activos As Decimal = 0
For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
    If dt.Rows.IndexOf(r) = 0 Then
    Else
        conexiones += Convert.ToInt32(r.Item(1))
        bajas += Convert.ToInt32(r.Item(2))
        reconex += Convert.ToInt32(r.Item(3))
        cortes += Convert.ToInt32(r.Item(4))
        variacion += Convert.ToInt32(r.Item(5))
        activos = Convert.ToInt32(r.Item(6))
    End If
Next
gv.DataBind()
gv.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter
gv.FooterRow.Cells(0).Text = "Total"
gv.FooterRow.Cells(1).Text = Math.Round(conexiones, 0).ToString()
gv.FooterRow.Cells(2).Text = Math.Round(bajas, 0).ToString()
gv.FooterRow.Cells(3).Text = Math.Round(reconex, 0).ToString()
gv.FooterRow.Cells(4).Text = Math.Round(cortes, 0).ToString()
gv.FooterRow.Cells(5).Text = Math.Round(variacion, 0).ToString()
gv.FooterRow.Cells(6).Text = Math.Round(activos, 0).ToString()
gv.ShowFooter = True
```

But it only displays an empty `<footer></footer>` tag after the table body and I can't find the reason why,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you call `DataBind()` before you add data to the footer.

Comment: @VDWWD I get what you're saying, but the thing is I can't add data to the footer and then bind the data, because I get a null pointer exception (I guess the footer gets created when binding the data)

Comment: Why did you tag this as C#?